# Why is this JSONObject not a JSONArray?

Tags: java, arrays, org.json

i am the following codes in javascript

```
var people = {
    "users" : [{id : this.getJID().toString()},{id : this.getJID().toString()}],
    "body" : messageBody
}
```

on my server end, I have the following:

```
JSONObject b = new JSONObject(jsonstring);
JSONArray users = b.getJSONArray("users");
```

I cannot get users because I will have the following exception.

> org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["users"] is not a JSONArray.

I tried to cast to JSONObject but also gets error.

```
JSONObject o = b.getJSONObject("users");

org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["users"] is not a JSONObject.
```

What is wrong??

Comment: What is the contents of "jsonstring"?

Comment: jsonstring is JSON.stringify(people). using http://json.org/java/ lib..

Comment: And what is `people` and the result of the `stringify` call?

Comment: @Thomas - dont quite understand. people is the js var. JSON.stringify(people) is what i sent via POST to my server side.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right - missed that. Still, what do you get on the server side? If you print `jsonstring`, what does it look like?

Comment: {"users":"[{\"id\": \"user1@192.168.0.147/spank\"}, {\"id\": \"user1@192.168.0.147/spank\"}]","body":"test"}

Comment: fyi, i can get the body message..

Comment: @anewbie: The JSON is serialized wrongly. The value of `user` is not an array but a string: `{"users":"[...]","body":"test"}` There should be no quotes around `[...]`. That's why you get the error. It seems like you recursively serialized the contents of `people`.

Comment: but this is all i did.. ajax.send(JSON.stringify(people));

Comment: What does the ajax.send code do then?

Comment: @anewbie: Maybe `people` already contains JSON.

Answer (score 1):

As noted above:

> The JSON is serialized wrongly. The value of user is not an array but a string: {"users":"[...]","body":"test"} There should be no quotes around [...]. That's why you get the error. It seems like you recursively serialized the contents of people